# Pulling a token/value from JSON without JObject.Parse in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net

So I will be getting in a JSON as a string from some request. It is formatted like:

```
{
    "Name" : "SomeName",
    "Version" : "V0001",
    "Year" : "1999",
    "MoreComplicatedObjects" : {...}
}
```

This JSON that is coming in will be quite large and I would like to see if it would be possible to get Name, Version, and Year without having to do a JObject.Parse(string). I'm just a little worried about possibly having to parse this entire string when instead I could just get what I need and be done with it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `JObject.Parse` uses `JsonTextReader`, so there's nothing to stop you reading through the JSON yourself at a lower level.

Comment: Just create the model with your required properties and ignore other properties then parse the json object.

Comment: @Abu are you sure they're actually ignored at the parser level? I did a minimal test by setting `MaxDepth = 1` and I still got an exception even when the model didn't contain the deeper field. [New example](https://rextester.com/YEDDE68788): the `Nested` property isn't referenced in the model but there's still an exception thrown. The only way I see this happening is if JSON.NET still parses all of this internally.

Comment: @jimonthycricket, can you please post your full json object including the part you want to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class which just has those properties. Any extra properties are ignored

```cs
class Foo
{
    public string Name;
    public string Version;
    public string Year;
}
```

```
var json = @"
{
    "Name" : "SomeName",
    "Version" : "V0001",
    "Year" : "1999",
    "MoreComplicatedObjects" : {...}
}
";

var fooObject = JsonConvert<Foo>(json);
```